# Take single code out from excel cells

Tags: excel

I have many cells on this format: `JAN 2012` on excel (as shown on the on the image below), and I need to take it out from many cells (so I can´t do it manually. Does anyone knows how to make it?  I´ve already tried using the functions "Right" and "LEFT" with the "concatenate one... but it didn´t work...

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "take it out from"?  If you just want to have the date show in G49 as you show in your picture, then G49: =F53, and format it as "mmm/yy"  If you want something else, please be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I used `"=datevalue"` to convert text to date

Answer (score 0):

Either do a "find and replace" (Ctrl-H), on your whole column, and find the incorrect character (') and replace it with nothing.

If that does not work, for some reason, then VBA would work if you have already tried `LEFT` and `RIGHT` worksheet functions, etc.